# How can I divide the foreach result for 2 div?

Tags: php, css, arrays, foreach

Here's the thing: I have a foreach loop that adds inputs dynamically. I need it to place part of them in one div, the rest in another. The current code is the following:

```
$sqla=mysql_fetch_row($sql);

$x=1;
if($x<50)
{
?>
    <div class="area area-1">
<?  
    foreach($sqla as $key=>$values){
        if ($key == "0") {
            continue;
        }
        $icheck = ($values > 0) ? "icheck" : "";
        $ichecked = ($values > 0) ? "isChecked" : "";

        echo "<label class='label-area label-".$values['num".$x."'][$x]." ".$ichecked."'><input name='data[ar][".$x."][]' type='checkbox' value='".$x."' title='".$x."' class='".$icheck." archeck1'><span class='label-num'>".$x."</span><span class='label-check-mark'></span></label>";

       if ($key == "50") {
           break;
        }
        $x++;

        if ($values > 0) {
            $new_rand_arr[] = $values;
        }
    }
?>
</div>
<?
}else{
?>
    <div class="zodiak ar-1">
<?
    foreach($sqla as $key=>$values){
        if ($key == "50") {
            continue;
        }
        $icheck = ($values > 0) ? "icheck" : "";
        $ichecked = ($values > 0) ? "isChecked" : "";

        echo "<label class='label-area label-".$values['num".$x."'][$x]." ".$ichecked."'><input name='data[ar][".$x."][]' type='checkbox' value='".$x."' title='".$x."' class='".$icheck." archeck1'><span class='label-num'>".$x."</span><span class='label-check-mark'></span></label>";

        if ($key == "62") {
            break;
        }
        $x++;

        if ($values > 0) {
            $new_rand_arr[] = $values;
        }
    }
?>
</div>
<?  
}
?>
```

The output puts it all in the first div, but none in the "zodiak ar-1" one. The target thing is everything after the 50-th key to go into that div. Hope that managed to explain the issue...
Thank you

Comment: Your `if` statement is always `true` cause you define `$x=1;` and check it by `if($x<50){ ...`

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Also, never use `mysql_*`

Comment: if you know how many times you loop, use for instead of foreach, just add in the second div after the 50th,

Comment: Well your `if($x<50)` is outside the loop so initially it will always be `<50` so you will never get into the ELSE

Comment: do one foreach only and build the two divs inside the foreach. When you reach 50 iterations close the first and open the second. Your code is not efficient by double iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are doing this:

```
$x=1;
if($x<50)
{
 // your code
} else {
  // your code
}
```

The problem is that you do a foreach INSIDE the `if` statement, so `$x < 50` will ALWAYS be true because just before you do `$x = 1`.

Now in both `foreach` loop you do this :

```
foreach($sqla as $key=>$values){
   if ($key == "0") {
       continue;
   }
   // your code
}

foreach($sqla as $key=>$values){
    if ($key == "50") {
        continue;
    }
    // your code
}
```

So you use a var `$x` that you increment each turn but you have a `$key` that you use too to check if value is `<50` or not?

So try something like this :

```
$new_rand_arr = array();

$open_first_div  = false;
$open_second_div = false;

$html = "";

foreach($sqla as $key=>$values){
   if ($key < "50") { 

       // You open your first div one time
       if (!$open_first_div) {
           $html .= "<div class=\"area area-1\">";
           $open_first_div = true;
       }

       $icheck = ($values > 0) ? "icheck" : "";
       $ichecked = ($values > 0) ? "isChecked" : "";

       html .= "<label class='label-area label-".$values['num".$x."'][$x]." ".$ichecked."'><input name='data[ar][".$x."][]' type='checkbox' value='".$x."' title='".$x."' class='".$icheck." archeck1'><span class='label-num'>".$x."</span><span class='label-check-mark'></span></label>";

       if ($values > 0) {
           $new_rand_arr[] = $values;
       }

   } else {
        // You close your first div and open the second div
       if (!$open_second_div) {
           $html .= "</div><div class=\"zodiak ar-1\">";
           $open_second_div = true;
       }

       $icheck = ($values > 0) ? "icheck" : "";
       $ichecked = ($values > 0) ? "isChecked" : "";

       $html .= "<label class='label-area label-".$values['num".$x."'][$x]." ".$ichecked."'><input name='data[ar][".$x."][]' type='checkbox' value='".$x."' title='".$x."' class='".$icheck." archeck1'><span class='label-num'>".$x."</span><span class='label-check-mark'></span></label>";

       if ($values > 0) {
           $new_rand_arr[] = $values;
       }

   }
}

// After the foreach your close your div
$html .= "</div>";

// You display it
echo $html;
```

Comment: That code is much tougher that I thought...now lists all the labels and then the two divs which are empty....

Comment: When you add the labels, you MUST do : `$html .= "<label>...</label>;"` so the label will be INSIDE the div, did you do that?

Comment: I edited my answer will the whole code according to your question

Comment: Thank you, so much for your help, Mickael! That worked. You are a life saver!

Comment: Glad to help you